# ServiceTracker doesn't find an existing service

Tags: osgi

I am using ServiceTracker in order to located registered services in our OSGi environment.
I have got this code in the Bundle Activator start method:

```
    logger.debug("looking for MyService");
    tracker = new ServiceTracker(ctx, MyService.class.getName(), null);
    tracker.open();
    MyService = ((MyService)tracker.getService());
    if (MyService != null)
    {
        logger.debug("found MyService");
    }
```

The problem is this:

- If I install and start my bundle the
  service can be found and used.
- If I restart OSGi completely MyService cannot be
  found by my bundle (i.e. is NULL) even though that
  my bundle is on status ACTIVE.
- If I stop/start my bundle MyService
  can be found and used again.

I don't think the problem lies in the bundle that hosts MyService since it is clearly there and can be found again if my bundle is restarted.

It looks like my bundle loads before the one that has the dependent service in it which is why it can't find it after a restart and can find it after I restart my bundle.

An indication to that is that if I list available services using

```
ServiceReference[] ref = tracker.getServiceReferences();
```

it finds no services after the OSGi restart but it does find MyService after I stop/start my bundle that looks for it.

I was trying to set Require-Bundle reference to the bundle that hosts MyService hoping that the OSGi framework will recognize the dependency but it didn't help.

Any ideas...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the `ServiceTracker` from the `BundleActivator`, you effectively freeze the entire framework (so, no other bundles can be started at the same time). If the bundle that provides your service starts *after* the bundle with the tracker, you will not see the service. This explains why stopping and starting your bundle later on gives you your service.

Now, if you want to track and use the service, I would spawn a new thread to do that, and use `waitForService` in stead of `getService`.

Comment: Thanks, that probably explains why. The ServiceTracket recommends not using waitForService() in the start method ("It is strongly recommended that waitForService is not used during the calling of the BundleActivator methods. BundleActivator methods are expected to complete in a short period of time. "). In that case, what would be a better way to get a reference to the service? Perhaps saving a reference to bundlecontext in the Activator class and then call ServiceTracker.getService() from the bundle code itself?

Comment: If you need access to the `BundleContext` from your bundle, you should indeed save it from the `Activator` somehow, and later use that to get your services. I would also encourage you to take a look at some systems that you with this, such as Declarative Services from the OSGi spec, iPojo or the Apache Felix Dependency Manager.

Comment: I tried waitForService and now the bundle hangs on STARTING and it hangs the entire bootstrap so I don't think that waitForService is a good idea...

Comment: We use Equinox as the framework and Guice/Peaberry for DI but Guice/Peaberry have already done the bindings of this service, all I need now is to consume it as a client.

Comment: If you don't use waitForService from a new thread, for sure it will hang. If you have a DI solution already, why don't you use it from your client bundle?

Comment: because if I use it from the client side then I will need to do another wiring of all the object classes MyService depends on otherwise Guice/Peaberry won't start the bundle. That's fine when writing the service as it gives me a way to determine if there is a problem with the service dependencies before runtime but from the client side all I really need is a reference to that service without rewiring...

Comment: You should **never** use `waitForService` in the start method of a BundleActivator. It will block the completion of the activator which is a no-no.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing the right thing by using a ServiceTracker. But the problem is expecting the service being tracker to be available in the activator. You do not want to establish an ordering constraint between starting your bundle and the bundle registering the service. Unless you really need to use the service in the activator's start method (and you probably shouldn't), just get the service later when you actually need.

Another idea is to consider using Declarative Services to manage your service dependencies.

Comment: I am trying to deploy two bundles in OSGI but only one becomes active whichever deployed first.  I am not able to access the services from the second bundle.  Any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Services are very volatile in OSGi, so you should never expect one to be there when you need it or stay there after you get it. That's why your bundle should let itself be notified of services asynchronously.

The `ServiceTracker` class accepts a `ServiceTrackerCustomizer` (and is one itself) that is notified when services come and go.

Most of the time, the right way to use a service tracker is as follows:

```
// In BundleActivator.start:
this.serviceTracker = new ServiceTracker(bundleContext, MyService.class.getName(), null) {
    public Object addingService(ServiceReference reference) {
        // Get the service
        final MyService service = (MyService)this.context.getService(reference);

        // Do something with the service (e.g. inject it somewhere)
        // ...

        // Return the service to track it
        return service;
    }

    public void removedService(ServiceReference reference, Object service) {
        // Stop using the service (e.g. notify the objects that use it)
        // ...

        // Unget the service (very important!)
        this.context.unget(reference);
    }
}
```

Note that we only track the `MyService` services and don't use any customizer (we pass `null` as third parameter to the constructor), but override the two important methods instead. Another important method is `modifiedService`; please read the Javadoc for more information.

Managing this can quickly become a serious burden, so you should consider using higher level abstractions like declarative services (as suggested by another answer).